# BizTalk flat file produces CRLF even when empty data

Tags: xml, mapping, biztalk, flat-file

I have a xsd for flat file as a result from XML mapping, something like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://mynamespace" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://mynamespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="File" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="File">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="TransactionDate">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" repeating_delimiter_type="hex" repeating_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Items">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" repeating_delimiter_type="hex" repeating_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:annotation>
                      <xs:appinfo>
                        <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                      </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Item">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                          <b:recordInfo structure="positional" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                      </xs:annotation>
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:appinfo>
                              <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                            </xs:appinfo>
                          </xs:annotation>
                           <!-- My elements here -->
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>

                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" default="EOF" name="EOF" type="xs:string">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="2" justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="3" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The problem is when the xml have data, we have a correct result, something like:

```
line1
line2
line3
EOF
```

But when we have no data (XML just has only namespace)

```
<ns:SAPFile Channel="Eziemall" xmlns:ns="http://mynamespace" />
```

then the flat file is:

```
CRLF (for easy reading)
EOF
```

How can I get rid of CRLF from my flat file, I just want EOF at the first line.

Comment: Just a guess: do you, by any chance, have a postfix delimiter with a newline delimiter on your root record? This postfix delimiter will put a newline character before the EOF.

Comment: @PieterVandenheede You may be onto something: `preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false"` suggests there's a way to toggle this. It's been a while since I last used the BizTalk schema editor so I can't answer for sure.

Comment: @PieterVandenheede: below is all my xsd file, that part of ("<!-- My elements here -->" which I hide isn't important i guess. There is no postfix at all

Comment: @Filburt: I tried with preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" before but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your schema with a map where I didn't map anything to the destination and I didn't get the CRLF.

So the issue is in your map, rather than the schema.

You need to add a link to TransactionDate that suppresses that if there is no data.

[image]